# How to tell mercurial to 1. Discard local file 2. Use remote file

Tags: mercurial, conflict

Sometimes I can't seem to be able to track the merge conflicts.
I need a command that allows me to discard one of my uncommitted files  and then update it with the remote copy.

I tried hg revert  myfile followed by hg pull , hg commit
 but it still won't let me merge or commit.

It keeps telling me to fix unresolved conflict first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to let Mercurial know that you have resolved the conflict, using `hg resolve`. From the man page:

```
hg resolve [OPTION]... [FILE]...

redo merges or set/view the merge status of files

  Merges with unresolved conflicts are often the result of non-interactive
  merging using the "internal:merge" configuration setting, or a command-
  line merge tool like "diff3". The resolve command is used to manage the
  files involved in a merge, after "hg merge" has been run, and before "hg
  commit" is run (i.e. the working directory must have two parents). See "hg
  help merge-tools" for information on configuring merge tools.

  The resolve command can be used in the following ways:

  - "hg resolve [--tool TOOL] FILE...": attempt to re-merge the specified
    files, discarding any previous merge attempts. Re-merging is not
    performed for files already marked as resolved. Use "--all/-a" to select
    all unresolved files. "--tool" can be used to specify the merge tool
    used for the given files. It overrides the HGMERGE environment variable
    and your configuration files.  Previous file contents are saved with a
    ".orig" suffix.
  - "hg resolve -m [FILE]": mark a file as having been resolved (e.g. after
  having manually fixed-up the files). The default is to mark all
  unresolved files.
  - "hg resolve -u [FILE]...": mark a file as unresolved. The default is to
    mark all resolved files.
  - "hg resolve -l": list files which had or still have conflicts. In the
    printed list, "U" = unresolved and "R" = resolved.

  Note that Mercurial will not let you commit files with unresolved merge
  conflicts. You must use "hg resolve -m ..." before you can commit after a
  conflicting merge.
```

Here's how you pick up the version of the file from the server.
When you "hg pull", all changes from the server come into your copy of the repository. You can get the contents of a file in any revision using:

```
hg cat -r <rev> <file>
```

Use that to overwrite the local file, and commit.

Comment: Yes I can use a tool to resolve (all I have to do is select the file that was pulled from the server). Is there a way to achieve the same thing without using the tool?

Comment: "hg resolve" doesn't have to use a tool: you can use "-m" to mark the file as resolved. Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Before marking as resolved, I need to have the right file (the file in the server). I need to update my local copy with the remote copy. I don't want to merge. My local file needs to be discarded.

Comment: When you "hg pull", all changes from the server come into your copy of the repository. You can get the contents of a file in any revision using "hg cat -r <rev> <file>". Use that to overwrite the local file, and commit.

Comment: Cool Peter(+1). Exactly what I was looking for.